# HTMLUnit not picking up web form

Tags: java, forms, htmlunit

So I'm trying to parse a web page (http://www.bookholders.com/value.asp) using HTMLUnit, the current code I'm running is

```
   'WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.bookholders.com/value.asp");  
    System.out.println(page.getTitleText());
    System.out.println(page.getForms());
    HtmlForm form = page.getFirstByXPath("form[@action='publicprice.asp']"); 
    HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("isbn");
    textField.setText("0132151006");
    HtmlButton button = form.getInputByName("submit");
    button.click();'
```

I get a java.lang.NullPointerException when it tries to find the textField but I believe HTMLUnit is unable to find the form. How do I call the Form object? And also how do I make a selection of schools?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that code is unable to find the form.You can use `HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);` to get the form of the current page. 0 is the zeroth element of the form list.